# Using Gyroscope/Acceleromotor in Android browser?

Tags: android, browser, gyroscope

I know there are API for iOS since 4.2.1
What about android ? anyone know when can we access gyroscope data in Android browser?

Answer (score 2):

As i know, the most common releases (Android 2.2, 2.3) does not contain browser support for accelerometer, gyroscope, any motion api... You can read more here:
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-2-3-gingerbread-the-browser

But from Android 3, there are new Device Orientation events, which you can use: 
http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation.html